# Im trying to move all the data of repeated rows into a single row

Tags: r

Working with R programming. My original data has about 20,000 rows but some are repeats. I am trying to move those repeated entries information into a single row by those that have the same ID. Here is a small sample of what I mean
What I have:

```
ID Term     Class  Grade
123 Fall    MATH   B
123 Spring  ENGL   A
134 Fall    NA     NA
134 Spring  MATH   C
156 Fall    SCI    B
```

What I want -

```
ID   Term   Class  Grade Term   Class Grade
123  Fall   MATH   B     Spring ENGL  A
134  Fall   NA     NA    Spring MATH  C
156  Fall   SCI    B
```

```
My code: my_data2 <- my_data1 %>% 

  select(ID, Term, Class, Grade)
```

Comment: How wide are willing for the result to become? If you have an `ID` with an overloaded schedule of (say) 16 courses, then your resulting table will be 49 columns wide!  More generally, if the most "overloaded" `ID` in your dataset has `n` courses, accumulated over over any number of `Term`s, the result will be `3*(n - 1) + 4` columns wide, which seems unsustainable. On top of that, you'll have to rename your columns like `Term_1` | `Class_1` | `Grade_1` | `Term_2` | `Class_2` | `Grade_2` | ... | `Term_n` | `Class_n` | `Grade_n`, in order to avoid naming conflicts. Is this necessary or worth it?

Comment: As wide as they need to be unfortunately. The highest repeated ID is 10. So 1 row would have about 30 columns of information. From there I plan in filtering the data to display that which I need. My original data frame has 21 columns. I have filtered that data to only have 3 columns (not counting ID.) If I could just get an idea of how to organize this small sample Im sure my coworkers and I can expand to the larger data sample.

Comment: Got it.  Now does ordering (chronological or otherwise) matter when indexing `Class_1` | ... | `Class_2` | ... and so forth?  Is it simply in order of appearance?

Comment: Ordering does not matter. Simply in order of appearance.  I simply want to have each entry in its own column and i can work from there. Some of the answers are neat but not quite what i am looking for haha.

Comment: Awesome!  I should have the solution momentarily!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that leverages `dplyr` and `tidyr`.  Keep in mind that the columns here are clustered according to the original order of `Term` | `Class` | `Grade`, so the result will look like `ID` | `Term_1` | `Term_2` | ... | `Term_n`| `Class_1` | `Class_2` | ... | `Class_n` | `Grade_1` | `Grade_2` | ... | `Grade_n`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#
# Code to generate your dataset "my_data1".
#

my_data2 <- my_data1 %>%
  
  # # Establish an ordering to properly compare "Fall" to "Spring". NOTE: If you
  # # want to ALTER THE ORDERING, do so   |---- HERE ----|  from left to right.
  # mutate(Term = factor(Term, levels = c("Fall", "Spring"), ordered = TRUE)) %>% arrange(Term) %>%
  
  # Index each class according the order in which it appears for that ID.
  group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Class_Index = row_number()) %>% ungroup() %>%
  # "Pivot" the data into a wider format, to have one column for each indexed
  # Term, Class, and Grade.
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ID,
              names_from = Class_Index,
              values_from = Term:Grade,
              names_sep = "_")

# View result.
my_data2
```

Using a `my_data1` dataset like

```
my_data1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ID,  ~Term,   ~Class, ~Grade,
  123, "Fall",   "MATH", "B",
  123, "Spring", "ENGL", "A",
  134, "Fall",   NA,     NA,
  134, "Spring", "MATH", "C",
  156, "Fall",   "SCI",  "B"
)
```

your result for `my_data2` should look like

```
     ID Term_1 Term_2 Class_1 Class_2 Grade_1 Grade_2
  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1   123 Fall   Spring MATH    ENGL    B       A      
2   134 Fall   Spring NA      MATH    NA      C      
3   156 Fall   NA     SCI     NA      B       NA
```

Answer (score 0):

`reshape(df, idvar = "ID", timevar = "Term", direction = "wide")`

Output:

```
   ID Class.Fall Grade.Fall Class.Spring Grade.Spring
1 123       MATH          B         ENGL            A
3 134       <NA>       <NA>         MATH            C
5 156        SCI          B         <NA>         <NA>
```

Not exactly what OP asked for but the variable names are unique (tidy data).